# How to change login validity in mysql wamp 3.1.7

Tags: mysql, wamp

I recently updated my wamp to 3.1.7 version and now the GUI settings where you can change the `login cookie validity` in the browser is gone. Please see the image below for the screenshot.

Any idea for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to /config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 36000;
```

In /setup/lib/index.lib.php

```
$cf->getValue('LoginCookieValidity') > 36000;
```

If you don't already have a .htaccess file for your phpMyAdmin site, create one, and add the following line to override the default PHP session timeout:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 36000
```

I would not recommend altering this value in your main php.ini file, as it will allow a ridiculously long session timeout for all your PHP sites.

source: http://www.sitekickr.com/blog/increase-phpmyadmin-timeout/

Also try changing the cookie time session feature at:

Goto phpMyAdmin from web browser and goto

```
Server >> Settings >> Features >> "Login Cookie Validity" a
```

https://community.webfaction.com/questions/11343/no-activity-within-1440-seconds-please-log-in-again

Comment: May I ask the complete path for these? `/config.inc.php` and `/setup/lib/index.lib.php`

Comment: Hey, The main configuration file is /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Comment: Is that the complete path? I don't have it on my machine. I'm using windows by the way.

Comment: If for some reason the ./config.inc.php file doesn't exist, you will need to create one as per the Installation documentation.
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file

Comment: Do you know the exact path for wamp?

Comment: Hey Jonjie, Please check the installation path. Might be c:\wamp or search in local drive for wamp folder

Comment: Do you have easier way to do this? Unless it is from the official documentation.